# Adding two values from database together

Tags: c#, ado.net

How would i be able to add 2 parameter together?

i have this following code but it dont seem to work

```
balanceDB = readdata[("balance"+"overdraftLimit")].ToString();
```

Comment: What is readdata? You probably want something like: readdata["balance"] + readdata["oferdraftLimit"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
balanceDB = (readdata["balance"] + readdata["overdraftlimit"]).ToString();
```

This is assuming that you will do the casts. If you don't have casts in your code you need to do something like:

```
balanceDB = (Convert.ToDouble(readdata["balance"].ToString()) + Convert.ToDouble(readdata["overdraftlimit"])).ToString();
```

Adjust to fit whatever data type is necessary for these two fields.

Answer (score 0):

Considering that balanceDB is a string. Have you tried this:

```
balanceDB = readdata["balance"].ToString() + readdata["overdraftLimit"].ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are trying to do this with a DataReader, right?

You will need to read in each column separately, and concat them together. The code below assumes you are working with strings. If they are integers, or some other type, you need to cast accordingly

```
balanceDB = readdata["balance"].ToString() + readdata["overdraftlimit"].ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that readdata is a DataTable/datareader and what you want is to add values of balance and overdraftLimit.

```
int balanceDB;

balanceDB = (Convert.ToInt32(readdata["balance"])+Convert.ToInt32(readdata["overdraftLimit"]));
```

Supposed the value of balance =1 and overdraftLimit=1 then balanceDB will be equals to 2

Or if you just need to concatenate the two strings:

```
 string balanceDB;

balanceDB = readdata["balance"].ToString()+readdata["overdraftLimit"].ToString();
```

balanceDB will be equals to 11.

Regards